# How to get the listview content of the task manager in Windows?

Tags: delphi, listview, taskmanager, readprocessmemory

I try to get all items in Task manager Windows, but all what i get - empty Lines. I use RAD Studio XE7

```
procedure wtff(hwn: Thandle);
var
  ListView: HWND;
  ProcessId: DWORD;
  Process: Thandle;
  Size: Cardinal;
  MemLocal: Pointer;
  MemRemote: Pointer;
  NumBytes: NativeUInt;
  IconIndex: Integer;
  IconLabel: string;
begin
  ProcessId := 0;
  ListView := FindWindowEx(hwn, 0, 'SysListView32', nil);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(ListView, @ProcessId);
  Process := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_READ or
    PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, ProcessId);
  if (Process <> 0) then
    try
      Size := SizeOf(TLVItem) + SizeOf(Char) * MAX_PATH + 1;
      MemLocal := VirtualAlloc(nil, Size, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);
      MemRemote := VirtualAllocEx(Process, nil, Size, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT,
        PAGE_READWRITE);
      if Assigned(MemLocal) and Assigned(MemRemote) then

        // If Assigned memory

        try
          for IconIndex := 0 to SendMessage(ListView, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT,
            0, 0) - 1 do
          begin
            ZeroMemory(MemLocal, SizeOf(TLVItem));
            with PLVItem(MemLocal)^ do
            begin
              mask := LVIF_TEXT;
              iItem := IconIndex;
              pszText :=
                LPTSTR(Cardinal(MemRemote) + Cardinal(SizeOf(TLVItem)));
              cchTextMax := MAX_PATH;
            end;
            NumBytes := 0;

            if WriteProcessMemory(Process, MemRemote, MemLocal, Size, NumBytes)
              and Boolean(SendMessage(ListView, LVM_GETITEM, 0,
              LPARAM(MemRemote))) and ReadProcessMemory(Process, MemRemote,
              MemLocal, Size, NumBytes) then
            begin

              // Getting the text

              IconLabel :=
                string(PChar(Cardinal(MemLocal) + Cardinal(SizeOf(TLVItem))));
              if CaseSensitive then
              begin
                IconLabel := LowerCase(IconLabel);
                aText := LowerCase(aText);
              end;

              Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(IconLabel);
              /// ADD IN MEMO

            end;
          end;
        except
        end;
      if Assigned(MemRemote) then
        VirtualFreeEx(Process, MemRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
      if Assigned(MemLocal) then
        VirtualFree(MemLocal, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    finally
      CloseHandle(Process);
    end;
end;
```

So, in Memo i see only lots of empty lines.

Comment: Wouldn't be better (and easier) to just query the same information e.g. from WMI ?

Comment: There's a lot of stuff missing from your code, such as `LV_ITEM`, `ListView_GetItemCount`, `ListView_GetItem`, `LVIF_TEXT`, `Form1`... Also, why are you directly accessing `Form1` from an external procedure in the first place? Why not use the built-in tools to accomplish this? Which Windows versions do you intend to support? Windows 8 task manager is an entirely different application than prior versions.

Comment: ohh... Realy. I'm just very tired... 1 minute, i copy the actual code...

Comment: Why did you neglect error checking? What makes you think that you can attack task manager in this way? Why on earth wouldn't you just ask the system to enumerate its processes?

Comment: @Jerry: `ListView_GetItemCount` is a Win32 function (it's a macro, actually, in the API but implemented as a function wrapper in Delphi, in `CommCtrl`), as is `ListView_GetItem`. `LVIF_TEXT` is a predefined value (also in `CommCtrl`), and `Form1` is clearly a reference to a Delphi form. The poster is clearly doing the wrong thing (there are better ways to get running process info than trying to retrieve them from Task Manager's ListView), but that part of the code is clear if you're familiar with the WinAPI related to ListView controls.

Comment: @Ken Indeed, I was expecting more of an SSCCE (specifically the `compilable` part of it). I too would scrap this idea entirely and use the WMI instead - much easier and more compatible.

Comment: Sorry for bad code before.
Hope now it's actually, because i'm trying do this all day, and now i have "brain melts" :(

Comment: It's important to note which versions of Windows you want to support. Windows 8 has a brand new task manager.

Comment: You wrote all that code and you have no idea where does it fail? Start [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Debugging_Applications_Index).

Comment: I never writing in stack if i have some ideas, how it fix. Now i really no idea.
I tried most of variation and all of them return no results... sorry.

Comment: Why are you asking here if you won't heed the advice? Leaving aside the fact that screen scraping task manager is probably blocked for security reasons, and is in any case a really bad way to get the information, you've been advised to check for errors, and perform some debugging. I repeat the advise.

Comment: Thanks for advices. Task manager is not blocked, because i can get the number of lists and i can delete the item. 
I'm trying perform debugging, but it still no result.
I think that I am engaged in useless thing...

Comment: Nobody wants to help with the code because screen scraping task manager is wrong. On top of which you don't check for errors or do any debugging. You also don't appear to deal with the 32/64 bit mismatch. It looks like you copied this code but don't understand it. It's a big task for you to get from here to full working code. We just can't face doing it all in one question. If there was just one issue it would be more appealing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to code something similar.
For whatever reason, in some applications this method works, but in some it doesn't (especially when foreign process require elevated privileges).

Probably the foreign process window does not accept messages, as a measure of protection.
`SendMessage` may give error number 5 (ACCESS DENIED)
A possible workaround I see could be `dll injection` into process and issue `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx` from inside that process to make the window accept messages.

But this could be too much hassle and raise antivirus alarms..